# Blend removes animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, background, textbox, expression-blend

I created Windows Phone page in Expression Blend.
I added a TextBox element to the page and then I replaced control template for my TextBox by a copy of default template.
Blend generated everything for me: Style, Control Template and Visual States.

Then in Focused state I try to change Background brush of EnabledBorder from template and I get such message from Blend in the top of the editor:

> Your last action has caused some animations to be automatically deleted because they are no longer valid.

I know how to write this animation in xaml, but I want to do it with Expression Blend.

So, is it a bug of Expression Blend or I am missing something?
And are there any workarounds of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are encountering the same problem that I did. Check out my own answer to my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621494/494094