# Using local brush resources for Visual States

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to template a button in Blend and I have the following structure:

[image: General structure of the button template.]

What I would like to do is to change the background color of the button using **Visual States** when it is in the **MouseOver** state.

When it starts recording an animation for the **MouseOver** state I choose a **solid color brush** and everything looks fine:

[image: Choosing a solid color brush.]

[image: Animation is successfully captured.]

But when I choose a **local brush resource**, rather than a **solid color brush** and it keeps removing the animation:

[image: Choosing a local brush resource]

[image: The message showing that the animation is removed.]

[image: Animation is gone now.]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not supported in Expression Blend 4, but supported in Blend for Visual Studio 2012. One way to do it by hand is to use `ObjectAnimationsUsingKeyFrames`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource WindowCaptionButtonPressedBackgroundBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

(This is exactly what Blend for Visual Studio 2012 does.)